# use of atoi() function in C

Tags: c

I tried reading in the atoi() description on some sites but couldn't get an answer.
What will

```
int i = atoi("000000000000000000003");  
printf("%d", i);
```

result in? Will it be 3 or will it return an error (0 in atoi()'s case)?
I don't currently have any means of compilation available so I cant just test it.

Edit: Accidentally had 000000000000000000003 instead of "000000000000000000003" as an argument.

Edit2: The part about testing is is no longer relevant, thanks.

Comment: `int i = atoi(000000000000000000003);` Probably segfault, if the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: "I don't currently have any means of compilation available" -[Liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3g4wJb$2) or [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/YVXoSE) as Potatoswatter suggests

Comment: Or [IDEone](http://ideone.com) when that's offline

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi, atoi takes `const char *str` as input

Comment: it should be int i = atoi("000000000000000000003"), in that case it returns 3 as a result.You can use http://codepad.org/ as online compiler for this.

Comment: @KarthikT: Check out [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/).

Comment: @JesseGood nice, havent come across that before thanks

Comment: You can _always_ "just test it". Even if it means you have to wait. Patience is a virtue, grasshopper.

Comment: or (http://stacked-crooked.com/) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** use [`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) at all. It is not safe as it doesn't check the input.

Consider using [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Regarding your question: it won't work. A parameter must be const char* , what you have in your example is an int. (After your edit, it will return **3**)

Comment: I am forced to use it because part of the exercise includes secure programming, they expect me to check for the problems with atoi() myself;

Comment: Part of the exercise involves secure programming so they've got you using `atoi`? Lol...

Comment: Yep, they want me to check every edge case myself at least for something.

Comment: That's all right, check it, but then remember to never, ever, use it again.

Comment: `as it doesn't check the input.` --> Where do you quote this from? The main reason why this is unsafe is that the standard says `If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined.`

Answer (score 2):

According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atoi.html), which references the C90 standard, `atoi` is a wrapper for [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html) in base-10, and that function expects

> If the value of base is between 2 and 36, the expected form of the subject sequence is a sequence of letters and digits representing an integer with the radix specified by base, optionally preceded by a '+' or '-' sign. …
>
> The subject sequence is defined as the longest initial subsequence of the input string, starting with the first non-white-space character that is of the expected form. The subject sequence shall contain no characters if the input string is empty or consists entirely of white-space characters, or if the first non-white-space character is other than a sign or a permissible letter or digit.

So the zeroes will not faze it; it will return 3.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) reference:

> The function first discards as many whitespace characters (as in isspace) as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is found.

In your example the first character found is a non-whitespace (0!=white space character) so..

> starting from this character, takes an optional initial plus or minus sign followed by as many base-10 digits as possible, and interprets them as a numerical value.

that means that the function reads characters as long as the are digits based on 10 as base until if finds one character which isn't, for example a `(` or a `l`etter or a null-terminating character `\0`. Then...

> Interprets its content as an integral number, which is returned as an int value.

So your example is like this:
`int i=000000000000000000003;`
If you `printf("%d", i)` this value the machine will output `3`, same as your problem.

Comment: You should quote from the standard. I just read there and the wording is completely different from the standard, which makes a difference between a usable function and a bad one.

Comment: By standard you meand [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atoi.html) right? I have read it and it seems like to me that cplusplus has a more in-depth analysis of the function, but that's maybe me..

Comment: By standard, I mean [this C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (The C++ standard refers back to C standard on this point). cplusplus just copied part of the standard from the strtol function, which describe the behaviour in the normal case correctly, but deviates a bit when it talks about the error case (the deviation makes a difference between usable and unusable).